# Client did not receive any status from worker

Tags: php, gearman

Im using code exactly like in example #2 from http://php.net/manual/en/gearmanclient.donormal.php

Im getting expected worker output like in the manual

Problem is, my client did not produce expected output like in the manual

**Expected client output is:**

```
Starting
Sending job
Status: 1/6 complete
Data: H
Status: 2/6 complete
Data: e
Status: 3/6 complete
Data: l
Status: 4/6 complete
Data: l
Status: 5/6 complete
Data: o
Status: 6/6 complete
Data: !
Success: !olleH
```

**Instead this is what i got:**

```
Sending job
Success: Hello!!olleH
```

As far as i know, the worker worked as expected, it really sending back data to the client, thats why i get `Sucess: Hello!!olleH` instead of just `!olleH`, what i wonder is why polling the status does not work

After some debugging, i figure out that the `do..while` block only run once
The `$gmclient->returnCode()` return `0`
Looks like my client did not receive any status from the worker

**Some info:**
os : ubuntu 14.04 (vagrant)
gearmand version : 1.1.12
extension version : 1.1.2
libgearman version : 1.1.12

Im new to gearman, what i want to achieve is the same client output as in the manual, any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the documentation is either outdated or flat out wrong. I did a little digging and there was a change to the Gearman::do() function in 0.21 that makes it run until completion or error. See http://gearman.info/libgearman/gearman_client_do.html.

> Changed in version 0.21: GEARMAN_PAUSE will no longer be returned. A do operation will now run till completion or error.

Instead, I think it is preferred to do what you're intending to with a Task and some callbacks:

```
<?php

# Client code

# Create our client object.
$gmclient= new GearmanClient();

# Add default server (localhost).
$gmclient->addServer();

echo "Sending job\n";

# Send reverse job
$gmclient->setCompleteCallback('gm_complete');
$gmclient->setDataCallback('gm_data');
$gmclient->setStatusCallback('gm_status');
$gmclient->addTask("reverse", "Hello!");
$gmclient->runTasks();

function gm_data(GearmanTask $task) {
  echo "Data: {$task->data()}".PHP_EOL;
}

function gm_complete(GearmanTask $task) {
  echo "Success: {$task->data()}".PHP_EOL;
}

function gm_status(GearmanTask $task) {
  echo "Status: {$task->taskNumerator()} / {$task->taskDenominator()}".PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```